# Change PIL image pixels and display it afterwards --> result black horizontal line

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

Consider the follow Code

```
# Get an list of pixels of the current image and convert it into an array
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('path_to_your_image')
pixels = np.array(list(im.getdata())) # get rbg values of each pixel and store it in an array
```

For my case i get for example:

```
pixels[:6]  --->

array([[ 60, 101,  59],
   [ 60, 101,  59],
   [ 60, 101,  59],
   [ 60, 101,  59],
   [ 60, 101,  59],
   [ 60, 101,  59]])
```

I want to manually change each pixel (for example: filter kernel) and then display the result in form of a picture. Lets say I just multiplied each rbg value with one (= picture is unchanged) and i want know to display the result (pixels must be converted back into a picture):

```
im_new = Image.fromarray(pixels)
im_new.show()
```

The picture will just show a straight horizontal black line. I checked the pixel values for the new picture

```
test = np.array(img_new.getdata())
test[:6]

---> array([ 60, 101,  59,  60, 101,  59])
```

Image.fromarray(pixels) creates a 1D array of the previous 2D array pixel. That is probably the reason why a 1D Line is displayed. Does someone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getdata` flattens the pixels into a 1D list (see [docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getdata)).

In order to keep the structure, use this (from the [docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.fromarray)):

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
im = Image.open('hopper.jpg')
a = np.asarray(im)

# change array here

im = Image.fromarray(a)
```